# get 2D array from another 2D array using if statement in c

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array (`big_array`) and there are four values inside of it = 1,

I want to get the indexes of these four values and put them in the first index of each array in another 2D array (`small_array`) one by one.

I tried this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {  
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < size; x++) {
            if (big_array[i][j] == 1) {
                small_array[x][0] = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I get only the index of the last value=1 in all of array of 'small_array'.

Comment: The indices of the items that equal 1 in a matrix are a list of `{row,col}`. Do you have some kind of homomorphism that will encode this into a `small_array`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you are trying to achieve, but If you're trying to store the second index of each element that equals 1 of the `big_array` in the first column of the `small_array`, then here is how :

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 3)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (big_array[i][j] == 1)
            {
                small_array[x][0] = j;
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```